# How to fix the Build path of a class android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I am not using this class in my project, but when I write code in the `*.xml` file then the warning problem arise in the Android Virtual Device preview window.

[image: warning for Rendering Problem in Android Studio ADV preview window]

Comment: development tool eclipse ?

Comment: Sometimes, I also get the same problem. Just try to click on the refresh icon on the same window and see if it solves your problem.Otherwise follow the android studio installation guide again.

Comment: no. its Android Studio @sasikumar

Comment: i did that already, but still it was not working .. @Rudra

Comment: I just ignore this message. Everything works just fine :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` to inheirt from `NoActionBar`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: thanks. its worked.
but 
i was using 

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

could you please tell me why the problem arise ??

Comment: @TanvirHossain when answer (solution) helped you, remember to mark answer as accepted (tick on the left)

Comment: could you please tell me why the problem arise ??.. i was using this AppTheme in styles.xml  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: @TanvirHossain it's not Android Studio or Eclipse problem; `AppCompatActivity` is newer version of `ActionBarActivity`. `ActionBar` is deprecated, but some references still exist in library. `Toolbar` is used now instead of `ActionBar`.